# Проверка пользовательского ввода

Tags: регулярные-выражения, c#

Пользователь вводит строку вида

```
**:**:****
```

где `*` - это цифра, а `:` - это двоеточие. Как проверить, что ввод соответствует шаблону?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проверить строку на соответствие шаблону можно, используя регулярные выражения.

```
private static readonly Regex template = 
    new Regex(@"^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{4}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);

public static bool Validate(string input)
{
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) && template.IsMatch(input);
}
```